# Is memory will be destroyed or not?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi i have code like below , just added logic view not full syntax

```
int globalVar;

static void* average()
{
  void *data = NULL;

  if (true)
  {
      globalVar = getAverage();
      data = ((void *)&globalVar);
  }

  return (data);
}
```

So my concern is if i return globel variable by assigning to local pointer then will it be in memory or lost when function end?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no memory leak here. Memory leaks only arise from unbalanced `malloc` and `free` calls, and there is nothing like that going on here.

(Assuming `getAverage()` doesn't *itself* leak).

Answer (score 1):

> So my concern is if i return globel variable by assigning to local pointer then will it be in memory or lost when function end?

No.

If it's a global variable then it'll have *static storage duration* and it won't be "lost" when returning it through a local pointer.

When you access any object through a pointer, what matters is the storage duration of the object you access; not the storage duration of the pointer. So, assuming your global variable has static storage duration (usually defined outside functions at the top of source files), you are fine.